# How many views is too many views in a layout

Tags: android, game-engine

I am making a simple card game app for a school project - Basically it has an image and a button.

Each time the button gets clicked, the top card floats upward and away (like a vertical tinder swipe) revealing the bottom card.

The cards have custom images that are randomly generated by a backend server that returns a bunch of jpeg urls (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSeTr.jpg, ...)

I plan on implementing this by just having a framelayout and 10 image views, and each time a card is aniamted off screen I will destroy a top view (and pop a corresponding array element off the list in my activity) - and when the card number drops low (e.g. 5 left) I will make another call to the server and get more urls and generate 10 more which I will insert under the current cards (and respectively push some new elements into the array - which is how I plan to keep track of view/data)

So there is potentially maximum 15 image views at a time, would this be a problem? Is there a better way to implement this behavior?

[image]

Comment: A bigger issue may be the memory management than 15 views if the images are a full screen images.

Comment: @Tigger images are 100kb each

Comment: I'm guessing 100kb is their compressed size. How big is each image as a BMP (not compressed).

Comment: @Tigger heres one card (http://i.imgur.com/oXrPhiC.jpg). Im getting the vibe this wont be feasible. Any recommendations on how to implement desired behavior?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but it may not be as simple as you first thought. That is all. Why not make a test project and find out :] BTW, moving to a an OpenGL 3D engine would make this very easy.